# Getting multiple $_POST values from multiple selectBoxes

Tags: php

Ive got a loop which generates multiple select boxes like this:

[image]

The code that generates the selectboxes is as follows:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $team1 = $row['team1'];
    $team2 = $row['team2'];
    $id[$i]= $row['event_id']; 

    echo'<h3>'.$team1.' VS '.$team2.'</h3>';
    echo'<select name="id[]">'; //this is team winner selectbox
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team1'].'">'.$team1.'</option>';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team2'].'">'.$team2.'</option>';
            echo'</select>';    

            echo'By <select name="score[]">'; //this is score selectbox
            echo'<option value="1">1</option>';
            echo'<option value="2">2</option>';
            echo'<option value="3">3</option>';
            echo'<option value="4">4</option>';
            echo'<option value="5">5</option>';
            echo'<option value="6">6</option>';
            echo'</select>';    
}//while
```

Here comes the tricky part I need to extract the selected results from the selectboxes,which contains values of **'event_id, 'winning_team, 'score'** and insert into a database:

Im using the following code to extract selected results, which I could get to work but upon adding the score field I started getting errors:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $winner){
    echo  $winningScore = $_POST['score'] ;
    $winnerb = $id[$key];
    echo($winner."-".$winnerb);
    echo $winningScore;
    $sql="INSERT INTO picks(member_nr,event_id,pick,score)
            VALUES('$userId','$winnerb','$winner',$winningScore)";
            mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
}//for
```

My natural assumption would be to add a forloop in the forloop but that will cause the inside loop to do to many iterations, so im using the logic of assigning the $POST['score'] value to an array $winningScore and then sending that to database query but I get an error of "array to string conversion" for the $winningScore array.

UPDATE: 
$winningScore contains the following values, which is correct based on score selection:

[image]

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Try using var_dump to see what is going on

Comment: `$winningScore ` it's an array. Your selects so strange, `score[]` its used for multiple options, but you have lost `multiple` attribute

Comment: @JoeDF please see update on question, for result of var_dump()

Comment: @Marilee if you need to save scores in one row, you could serialize score array or `implode` it

Comment: I had already posted, I knew it was an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using you result rows as a string, but they are arrays.

You need to loop through them

```
$length = count($winningScore);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $winningScore[$i]; //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`score` is an array, but you are not selecting the current value. So if you replace `$winningScore = $_POST['score'] ;` with `$winningScore = $_POST['score'][$key] ;`, it should work.

Note though that your code is extremely insecure. You should use prepared statements to protect against SQL injection. And you should not be using `mysql_*` since it's deprecated since 2013, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead. Using prepared statements also has the benefit of speeding your code up, as you only need to prepare once, and can then execute with multiple values. Additionally, if `$team1` is in any way user supplied, you should encode special characters to protect against XSS.

Comment: Tim thanks! However if I do that the arrays Index gets added, for the score value which I find quite strange....I'll keep fiddling